# What is the recommended way to uninstall node, and install it with nvm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nvm

I have `Nodejs` installed in my Mac, but I did it the regular way. One of the requirements in my new job, is to install node with something named `NVM`, so, what is the recommended way to uninstall Node, and re-install it with the `NVM` stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install it on a `VPS`:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.11.1/install.sh | bash
```

[Read more here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-with-nvm-node-version-manager-on-a-vps#installation)